# How to switch between multiple user accounts when authenticating with Google ADC?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-api-python-client

I'm testing code using the google api python library locally and need to access several different google cloud accounts.

Each of these accounts (emails) have been given access to google analytics accounts. So, in order to access google analytics account 1,  I need to log into google account 1. To access analytics account 2, I need to log into google account 2. I need to pull data from many of these accounts at once, so I am looking for a way to authenticate all of these accounts.

From my testing, authenticating with ADC is on a per user basis and needs to be re-authenticated if you want to switch. How can I switch between multiple user accounts without having to run gcloud auth application-default login every time?

I tried setting the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable to point towards my saved ADC json credentials and authenticating with google.auth.default(), but that didn't work. I cannot use service accounts for various reasons.

Is there perhaps an easier way to authenticate multiple user accounts without using ADC and service accounts?

Comment: Google Cloud IAM supports cross-account privileges. Add your user identity and configure the correct roles for each project's IAM policy.

Comment: How does that help me with ADC? I already have cross account access through IAM but, I can only authenticate with one account at a time with ADC.

Comment: If you need to use multiple accounts with the CLI gcloud (application-default credentials), you must manually change them. You can configure multiple accounts but you must switch which one is the current one. My comment was to use one account and grant it the correct Cloud IAM roles on the projects you need to access. Otherwise, there is no solution for your requirement.

Comment: Note: ADC supports one identity. That identity can access any number of projects. I think you are using the term account instead of identity.

Comment: I added additional details to my post to make it more clear what I am trying to do.

Comment: If you must use user identities, then the CLI must reauthorize when you switch. That authorization happens in a web browser. That cannot be bypassed. Use one identity that has the required IAM roles on each project.

Comment: I have my email with Owner level access to project A. When I authenticate with that email, I can access that email's google analytics properties only. When I add that email with Owner level access to my other accounts, and authenticate with my main email, I still am only able to pull data from my main account. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -2):

run your application with

> $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/cred.josn python app.py